# traversing HTML doc child by child for its properties

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, tree-traversal

Need to traverse HTML doc using beautiful soup.
how can I check a element and then its child and so on:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source = requests.get('https:abc.com').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

root = soup.body.div.div.p
```

Is it possible to get its child and append it?
like beginning with

```
root = soup.body
root = soup.body.div
root = soup.body.div.div
```

after each child is added, need to get few properties

till its last child if found

Comment: Of course you can. I'll give you another example of a library: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: clarify  your question properly